# Get the java thread controlling the current class

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi I want to see what thread is running my current class. The reason for this is that I want to see if there are different threads running side by side based on where its exectuing code.

For example:

```
Public Class one {
   public void Method1 {
       Do something
       print out what thread is running here   
   }
   public void Method2 {
       doing something
   }
}

Class two {
   public void Method1 {
       Do something
       print out what thread is running here   
   }
   public void Method2 {
       doing something
   }
}
```

I would appreciate if there was something possible.

Answer (score 1):

To access the current thread within the current class, the Thread class has a static method called currentThread()

```
Thread.currentThread()
```

This might point you somewhere to giving answers what thread is handling what.

Comment: Different class methods could run in different threads, there are usually no specific thread associated with a class.

Comment: Thanks for expanding the answere! It helps!

Answer (score 1):

From threading point of view, your Class one and Class two are the same if the "Do something" parts are the same.

In Java, thread is a running entity and class is the procedure that the thread follows. You can not write a class that can only be run by a single thread. Any threads can run any classes.

Imagine Java class like a piano score and threads as pianist. A piano score can be played by more than one pianists, at the same time or at different time.

Given the example above, if the "Do something" parts are the same, you do not need to write two different classes, just one class will do the job:

```
Public Class ThreadTester {
   public void Method1 {
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
   }
   public void Method2 {
       doing something
   }
}
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks for the insight but it was ment to just be an very overview question and yes they are suppose to do different things.

Comment: If the "Do Something" parts are different, then just use Thread.currentThread().getName() to find out which thread is calling it.